# Parse Cloud code - Get Facebook profile picture fails with request code 302

Tags: facebook, parse-platform

I am using Parse and writing custom backend for my app. One thing that I need is to fetch Facebook profile picture and store it as an image file. But I am getting HTTP error code 302. Error 302 is due to redirection is something that I understand. I am looking for a solution for this scenario. No I can't fetch the picture from client and save the image file. I have to use Parse Cloud code to get the Facebook image and save it.

Here is the code I am using

```
Parse.Cloud.define("fetchFacebookProfilePicture", function(request, response) {

   Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
   var Image = require("parse-image");
   var user = Parse.User.current();

   if (user == null) {
        response.error("user is NULL");
   }

   var profilePictureURL = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+user.get("facebookId") +"/picture?type=large&return_ssl_resources=1";

   return Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
       url: profilePictureURL,
       method: "GET"
   }).then(function(response){
       //var image = new Image();
       response.success("All set");
   },function(error){
       response.error(error);
   });
});
```

This returns following error

{"uuid":"229e2f43-7533-0149-3bbc-c69970e04d7e","status":302,"headers":{"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*","Cache-Control":"private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate","Connection":"keep-alive","Content-Length":"0","Content-Type":"image/jpeg","Date":"Tue, 09 Dec 2014 19:38:40 GMT","Expires":"Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT","Facebook-API-Version":"v1.0","Location":"[https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/1920432_10153903894020578_1014472787_n.jpg?oh=40dc964b1d8dd29f618387944050fff4&oe=55059D07&**gda**=1427550917_a067d3a93e9a1dd1a92a258258deb415](https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-xpa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/1920432_10153903894020578_1014472787_n.jpg?oh=40dc964b1d8dd29f618387944050fff4&oe=55059D07&__gda__=1427550917_a067d3a93e9a1dd1a92a258258deb415)","Pragma":"no-cache","X-FB-Debug":"XydW5s6z3jTiOzFBmToC63AquyYBCc5Ye5W6vX88j7NFwsubSqqDxiQQnta7Gp0JU/4VYKFN6wY4qufMN+vHPA==","X-FB-Rev":"1523988"},"text":"","buffer":{"length":0,"parent":{"length":0},"offset":0},"cookies":{}}

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution/workaround for this?

Comment: Nope. I was not. And would be wonderful if there is a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the parameter `followRedirects` and setting it to true. For example, my request looks like:

`Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
     url: "https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId + "/picture",
     followRedirects: true,
     params: {
         type : 'large'
     }
})`

Also, you don't have to specify the `method` if  it's `GET` because that's implied.

Hope this helps.